# Terraform Azure AKS - how to set UAMI as kubelet_identity for AKS cluster

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

Looking at terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster) I have trouble determining how to assign UAMI as `kubelet_identity` for aks cluster.

The `identity { ... }` block which sets controlPlane UAMI as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#bring-your-own-control-plane-mi) is not what I am looking for.

The question is - is there a terraform way I can assign additional UAMI apart from the one in `identity {..}` block and use it to access ACR?

I want to set a separate UAMI as a kubelet identity as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#bring-your-own-kubelet-mi-preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a terraform way I can assign additional UAMI apart from the
> one in identity {..} block and use it to access ACR?

<s>According to the details you provided, you can create an additional UAMI and associate it with the AKS cluster kubelet identity, then assign the role to the UAMI, example code here:
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
name                = "example-aks1"
location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
dns_prefix          = "exampleaks1"</s>

```
  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  kubelet_identity {
    client-id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.kubelet.client_id
    object-id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.kubelet.principal_id
    user_assigned_identity_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.kubelet.id
  }
  ...
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "acr_for_kubelet" {
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.kubelet.client_id
  scope                = azurerm_container_registry.container_registry.id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
}
```

**Update:**

Actually, when you create the AKS and enable the system-assigned managed identity, then it will create the two user-assigned identities for the AKS cluster, one is to access other resources, and one is to manage the AKS cluster itself and this one is the kubelet identity.

It doesn't make sense to assign the kubelet identity permission to access the ACR. What you need to do is to assign the AKS identity permission to access the ACR. Or use the secret and service account inside the Kubernetes to access the ACR.

Comment: Thank you Charles. This covers ACR role creation part however how can I associate that kubelet UAMI with AKS?

Comment: @PMuz My mistake. I updated the answer. Actually, the `kubelet_identity` is the option for the AKS.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the version of terraform and azurerm provider you are using? I have tried that and got `"kubelet_identity this value cannot be set"`

Comment: @PMuz You can get details [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#kubelet_identity). I use the terraform version is 0.15.0

Comment: yup, though the link you reference leads to Attributes reference, not arguments. If I understand that correctly this is the list of the AKS cluster attributes that we can get via terraform but not necessarily set.

Comment: @PMuz Apologise for the mistake. That's the attribute of the AKS. I update the answer.

Comment: @PMuz Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: Hi Charles, regarding your update answer - what I am looking for is a solution where I set a User Assigned Managed Identity - not System Managed Identity. About UAMIs I want to have control over the UAMIs assigned. Setting a system managed one I won't know the UAMI details until I deploy it and it gets generated. I have raised an issue in azurerm repository and asked to enable kubelet_identity setting in their provider.

Comment: @PMuz AKS uses the user-assigned managed identity, it creates the user-assigned managed identity for the kubelet. It can be manually changed and it also makes no sense to assign the kubelet identity to access the ACR.

Comment: I guess all in all it comes to lack of this functionality in azurerm  -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#bring-your-own-kubelet-mi-preview

I would like to have control over the kubelet_identity UAMI.

Comment: @PMuz Of course, terraform lacks various features that are supported by Azure. If the terraform does not support the feature when Azure CLI command support, you can use the [`local-exec`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) to run the Azure CLI command in the Terraform code, this is the workload here.

Comment: Right, I could use local-exec though that would be for single azure-cli command. With the link I have provided looks like we would have to wrap the whole ARM template in terraform to deploy AKS cluster properly. The kubelet_identity can be only assigned wit `az aks create` and not with `az aks update` which would be useful in case of local-exec https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#create-a-cluster-using-kubelet-identity

Comment: @PMuz It seems yes. So I think you can create other resources needed and use the Azure CLI to create the AKS in the terraform.

Comment: Thanks for your time Charles. Accepting your answer as the closest one. Will post updates once azurerm provider allows to set kubelet_identity.

Comment: @PMuz You're welcome! I think it would be a long time to wait, but I wish that I'm wrong.

Comment: @CharlesXu According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#summary-of-managed-identities), and my experience, the Kubelet identity is what auths to ACR therefore it is necessary to grant the Kubelet UAMI `AcrPull` access to the ACR(s).

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an option in Terraform to assign UAMI as a kubelet identity.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#kubelet_identity

Example:

```
identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = var.control_plane_user_assigned_managed_identity_ids
  }

  kubelet_identity {
    client_id = var.kubelet_identity_client_id
    object_id = var.kubelet_identity_object_id
    user_assigned_identity_id = var.kubelet_identity_user_assigned_identity_id
  }
```

And as stated above you need to assign the kubelet identity to ACR as per doc (can be done via Terraform `azurerm_role_assignment`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#add-role-assignment

```
Use a pre-created kubelet managed identity
A Kubelet identity enables access granted to the existing identity prior to cluster creation. This feature enables scenarios such as connection to ACR with a pre-created managed identity.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this,

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "kube_cluster" {
  name                = local.cluster_name
  dns_prefix          = local.cluster_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 2
    vm_size    = "Standard_DS2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type                      = "UserAssigned"
    user_assigned_identity_id = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.managed_identity.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "acr_role_assignment" {
  principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kube_cluster.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
  scope                = data.azurerm_container_registry.container_registry.id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
}
```

You can view the whole **[script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kakaranish/eszop-infra/30828d524d9d9214ae84baded9dd2c4c7f981eb8/docker_based_deploy_azure/main.tf)** here

Comment: The thing here is that I want to set a separate UAMI as a kubelet identity as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#bring-your-own-kubelet-mi-preview)

The approach you have presented describes how to set UAMI for [controlPlane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#bring-your-own-kubelet-mi-preview)

Comment: Both links are going to the same page, may be i am wrong!

Comment: ah sorry the difference is between 
controlplane https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#bring-your-own-control-plane-mi and kubelet  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#bring-your-own-kubelet-mi-preview